# Question about composition of measurable function f and continuous function g being measurable:

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

I have to show the following:

Suppose $A$ is a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and $B$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. If $f: A \to B$ is measurable, and $g:B \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous, then $g \circ f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable.

We have defined a measurable function $f$ as satisfying $\{x \in A: f(x)>a \}$ is measurable for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$. I also know of a few sets that are measurable.

$\textbf{My Work Thus Far:}$  I realize that I need to show $(g \circ f)^{-1} ((a, \infty)) = f^{-1}(g^{-1}(a,\infty))$ is measurable for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$.  Since $g$ is continuous, we see that $g^{-1}((a,\infty))$ is an open set, which we can call X. We can write X as a countable union of open intervals. So, I need to show that $f^{-1}(X)$ is measurable, where X is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ which can be written as the countable union of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ measurable.

$\textbf{Edit:}$ Since $f$ is measurable, we see that $ Y = f^{-1}((a, \infty))$ is measurable for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$. We can find $a \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $X \subset Y$. Since Y is measurable, X is measurable as a subset of $X$.

Comment: I was just about to post this:).  Open sets are measurable.  Since $f$ is a measurable function, it follows that if $X$ is open, $f^{-1}(X)$ is measurable.  Not sure why the need for exhibiting a countable union of open intervals (unless you haven't proved measurability of open sets and need to do it once and for all).

As a side note, B. Vulikh's *Brief Course in the Theory of Functions* is absolutely unrivaled in its brief, clean, and transparent exposition of measure and integration theory.

Comment: That makes sense! I don't think that we have proved that if $X$ is open and $f$ measurable, then $f^{-1}(X)$ is measurable. Does my edit/attempt to finish the proof make any sense to you?

Comment: Actually it seems that subsets of measurable sets are not necessarily measurable, so my edit is incorrect. I'll look into the fact that $f^{-1}(X)$ is measurable. Thanks!

Comment: You are right, measurable subsets can have subsets that are not measurable.  For example, such is every non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What is your definition of a measurable subset of $\mathbb R$. There are at least two different standard definitions: Borel sets and Lebesgue measurable sets.  @user8482839

Comment: Here I'm talking about Lebesgue measurable sets.